# Rewrite Rule ignore the first part of a URL

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I want to have URLs like this:

some-company-name-deal-id-6.htm

So the rewrite rule should ignore all the bits before -deal- . I have tried this rule in my .htacess file but it did not work

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)-deal-id-(.*)\.htm$ deal.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I think you mixed up `\d+` and `.*` in your regex. Yours might match `6-deal-id-some-company-name.htm` instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right but when I try the other way around I can not get the id, shall I change deal.php?id=$1 to $2 ?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use the second capture group you would use `$2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct rule, if anyone else is interested.

RewriteRule ^(.*)-deal-id-(\d+).htm$ deal.php?id=$2 [QSA,L]